# Excel Chart Tooltip text change

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-charts

I have added a chart to excel using Add-ins, however I am unable to find a property/method to set its tooltip. As can be seen in image below, current tooltip text is 'Series "Year:" Point "2014"'. I want to remove words series and point from it to make like "Year: 2014  Value:37.0%"

[image: Tooltip of chart]